# How do I get my variables to my PHP script through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 variables which I am trying to pass to my PHP script for use in my sql statement but it does not seem to want to work for me. Any ideas why I cannot get a value for my $start and $limit variables? Am I missing something here?

Here are the 2 javascript variables on my index.php page:

```
var start = 0;
var limit = 5;
var reachedMax = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        infiniteScrollData();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //infinite scroll
    infiniteScrollData();
}
```

Then I have my javascript function in my javascript file that will send those 2 variables to my php page:

```
function infiniteScrollData(){

  if(reachedMax){
      return;
  } 
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "sortResults.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  {
            infiniteScrollData: 1,
            start: start,
            limit: limit
            },
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "reachedMax")
                reachedMax = true;
                else{
                    start += limit;
                    $("#rowDisplayResults").append(response);
            }   
        }
});
}
```

Then I have my 2 variables in my php script like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['infiniteScrollData'])){
    $start = check_input($_POST['start']);
    $limit = check_input($_POST['limit']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM topics DESC LIMIT :start, :limit";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Check input is just a function to clean the data

```
function check_input($dirtData) {
    $dirtData = trim($dirtData);
    $dirtData = strip_tags($dirtData);
    $dirtData = stripslashes($dirtData);
    $dirtData = htmlspecialchars($dirtData);
    $dirtData = filter_var($dirtData, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    return $dirtData;
}
```

Comment: What does the `check_input()` function?

Comment: There is no native check_input() function, can you show the code for check_input(). Is it part of a class?

Comment: I added the check input function to the question.

Comment: Your code looks ok, so you should check what's wrong. You're saying, that you cannot get values for `$start` and `$limit` variables, but it would better to add `var_dump($start, $limit);` before your SQL query and check whether their values are really empty or not. By the way, when adding comments you must use *@username* to mention users, otherwise they won't get your notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Victor, I'm still a little new to this. I added some additional code to show what I currently have.

Comment: What http response code do you get on your ajax request? What does `$_POST` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check_input method seems to be ok.

- Check whether you are getting the start, limit vars to your js code in the first place
- Check your URL whether its the correct url

Comment: Yes @THEWOLF, it seems that I am getting NULL values for them. so I guess that means they are not being passed to my .js file.

Comment: yeah thats the case.. Your php file is ok problem is in the js file.. try getting start and limit there ... just a litte problem I think

Comment: ok, I'll try figuring out how to get them over through my jquery file. Thanks for the help @THEWOLF

Answer (score 0):

To send data to the server(PHP) use FormData object.

for more info please check the link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData